# Gatsby custom Remark frontmatter variables not being passed into index.js

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby

first question on StackOverflow!

Using the Gatsby [blog template](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog), I've modified the graphql query and verified that it returns the correct data in GraphiQL, which is being pulled from a "redirect:" property in the blog post frontmatter.

Unfortunately it isn't being passed in the data when running the index.js file.

**gatsby-config.js**

```
feeds: [
          {
            serialize: ({ query: { site, allMarkdownRemark } }) => {
              return allMarkdownRemark.nodes.map(node => {
                return Object.assign({}, node.frontmatter, {
                  description: node.excerpt,
                  redirect: node.frontmatter.redirect,
                  date: node.frontmatter.date,
                  url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + node.fields.slug,
                  guid: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + node.fields.slug,
                  custom_elements: [{ "content:encoded": node.html }],
                })
              })
            },
            query: `
              {
                allMarkdownRemark(
                  sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
                ) {
                  nodes {
                    excerpt
                    html
                    fields {
                      slug
                    }
                    frontmatter {
                      redirect
                      title
                      date
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            `,
            output: "/rss.xml",
          },
        ],
```

**gatsby-node**

```
type Frontmatter {
      redirect: String
      title: String
      description: String
      date: Date @dateformat
    }
```

My code repository, https://github.com/tomvaillant/my_blog

Thanks for any support!

Answer (score 2):

You need to query for the `redirect` field in the same way you do in the `gatsby-config`. Your [query](https://github.com/tomvaillant/my_blog/blob/main/src/pages/index.js#L67) should look like:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        fields {
          slug
        }
        frontmatter {
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          title
          description
          redirect # <-- here
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to find where the data argument was being passed from and hadn't noticed that query... Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If the issue has been fixed please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the topic

Comment: Hey Ferran, new to the StackOverflow process. Has your answer been accepted? I've upvoted it and hope all is in order?

Comment: It's not, there's a check just where you upvote, you need to click it